# Ansible ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action:

Tags: ansible

I try to run a role/task, but i cant solve the following error:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/home/<user>/ansible/ilias6/roles/keysAndUsers/tasks/main.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: createUser and add to sudoer
  ^ here
```

This is my task:

```
---
- name: createUser and add to sudoer
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - /home/<user>/ansible/ilias6/roles/keysAndUsers/lists/userCreateList.yaml
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: "sudo, www-data"
    password: "{{ 'password' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"
    update_password: on_create
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash
    system: no
    createhome: yes
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  register: useradd
    
- name: change user password upon creation
  shell: chage -d 0 "{{ item.name }}"
  loop: "{{ useradd.results }}"
  when: item.changed
```

I noticed, if I comment out the section `vars_files` its fine. But i need the extern variables unfortunately

Comment: `vars_files` is a play level parameter, not task level.

Comment: Thank you! How can i make a reference to extern variables in a task section?

Comment: Move the above to your play, use include_vars in a precious task, use a file lookup with the from_yaml filter, refactor to put that in your role's defaults or vars so you don't have to include anything.....

Comment: You do not need var_files. Put your data in group_vars.

Comment: I had the same error, but for a different reason. What this post made me understand though, is that ansible will generate that error when you are trying to place the right thing in the wrong place. It doesn't necessarily mean that there is a syntax error, which was my first assumption.